# Why do i get String length error in plsql function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've made a function that needs a date inside the parameter. It should give an varchar2 return back: 'Weekend' or 'Doordeweeks'

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
    resultaat varchar2;
    datum date;
    function is_weekend(p_datum in varchar2)
    return varchar2
    is
    begin
        datum := to_date(p_datum, 'dd-mm-yyyy');
        if (to_char(datum, 'd') in ('1', '7')) then
            resultaat := 'Weekend';
            dbms_output.put_line(resultaat);
            return resultaat;
        else
            resultaat := 'Doordeweeks';
            dbms_output.put_line(resultaat);
            return resultaat;

        end if;
    end is_weekend;
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line(is_weekend('30-09-2018'));
    end;
```

Running this code gets me this pl/sql compilation error:

```
Error report - ORA-06550: line 2, column 15: PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Seems like something is wrong, anyone an idea what causing this error?

Comment: you just need `resultaat varchar2(1500);` as an example. i.e. a length should be defined for varchar2 type.

Comment: line 2 is: resultaat varchar2;  How long is that supposed to be?

Comment: Result of `to_char(datum, 'd')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` which may change at any time. Better use `to_char(datum, 'dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') IN ('sat', 'sun')` in order to be independent from that settings.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set size of varhcar2 thats it and doest need to use to_date to assign it to dateu like this:
sample input:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare       
    resultaat varchar2(20);
    datum date;
    function is_weekend(p_datum in varchar2)
    return varchar2
    is
    begin
        datum := p_datum;
        if (to_char(datum, 'd') in ('1', '7')) then
            resultaat := 'Weekend';
            dbms_output.put_line(resultaat);
            return resultaat;
        else
            resultaat := 'Doordeweeks';
            dbms_output.put_line(resultaat);
            return resultaat;

        end if;
    end is_weekend;
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line(is_weekend('30-09-2018'));
    end;
```

sample output:

```
Weekend
Weekend

begin
        dbms_output.put_line(is_weekend('30-nov-2018'));
    end;

Doordeweeks
Doordeweeks
```